# .NET - Return a List<CustomSerializableObject> from a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, list, serialization, web-services

Is it a **good idea** to try and return a strongly typed List of custom objects from a webservice?

Any pitfalls I should know about?

```
[WebMethod]
public List<CustomSerializableObject> GetList()
{
    List<CustomSerializableObject> listToReturn = new List<CustomSerializableObject>();

    listToReturn.Add(new CustomSerializableObject());
    listToReturn.Add(new CustomSerializableObject());
    listToReturn.Add(new CustomSerializableObject());
    return listToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any specific pitfalls to speak of other than possible support for third-parties that would want to communicate to it.  You would probably be better to return an array of objects by doing listToReturn.ToArray().  You can easily fill a new list on the client side if that is what you need.

Comment: What is the advantage of returning an Array of objects rather than a List?

Comment: As far as I know, a List will be converted to Array on return

Comment: The XML serialized representation of `List<T>` is interchangeable with `T[]`